# Laravel Paypal checkout

Tags: laravel, paypal, checkout

[Json view of my paypal after payment is made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFjxr.png)

I am desperately trying to access the description which is under the transactions array but can't seem to find a way! 
It's totally different if I want to access payment_method for instance all I do is this:
(By the way, I assigned this array to $method)
$method->payer->payment_method , but the same thing doesn't work if I want to access description. All I get is an error.

I'm using laravel 5.5, in case that makes a difference.

I'm doing this because I need to find a way to reference my product in the final page after the paypal payment has been made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like transactions in an array so if you would like the description of the first one that would look like this.

```
$method->transactions[0]->description
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: If my answer helped you don't forget to mark it as an answer :)